# Shutdown ubuntu server remotely

Tags: php, android, ubuntu-server

I have my Ubuntu Server 16.04 LTS running and at the end of the day I want to shutdown my server from android device.

I have created a `php` file (`API.php`) as below.

```
<?php
shell_exec("shutdown -P now");
?>
```

And in android app there is a button, and `OnClickListener` is as below:

```
String serverURL = "http://hostIP/API.php";
new LongOperation().execute(serverURL);
```

the `LongOperation` class is as below:

```
 private class LongOperation extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void>{

    private final HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    private String content;
    private String error = null;
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);


    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {

        progressDialog.setMessage("Shutting down...");
        progressDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {

        try {
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(params[0]);
            ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
            content = client.execute(httpGet, responseHandler);
        } catch (IOException e){
            error = e.getMessage();
            cancel(true);
        }

        return null;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void unused) {
        progressDialog.dismiss();
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "finished", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


    }
}
```

this code runs successfully on my localhost but when I put the ip of my server and rerun it, nothing happens.

How to shut down my ubuntu server successfully?

Comment: Permissions. Check if you have `sudo` permissions for the webserver user.

Comment: yeah, I have checked that too.

Comment: Do you set the permission to execute shell commands in the php.ini? Because in local maybe it is sets by default but in production not

Comment: Guys I have found the solution and If anyone want to know just write the comment.